# EPSON printer only printing in grayscale mode

Tags: printing, epson

My EPSON L4260 suddenly started to only print in black & white. Just a week ago it was perfectly fine. I tested it on my mobile and by itself and it's printing colors normally.

I checked the cups configuration but it's all right. Downloaded newer drivers from Epson, same result. The only hint I have is the fact that in the preferences I can see that the Print color mode is set to monochrome, even if I change it to color, it will roll back to monochrome (actually all configurations in this windows are not applied).

[image: Screenshot]

Any ideas of what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Running this command as the current user solved my problem.

lpadmin -p PRINTER_NAME -o print-color-mode-default=color

by
TheR

Answer (score 0):

This started happening to me after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I have reinstalled drivers too but with no change. This answer helped me https://askubuntu.com/a/1416784/1011687. It is probably an issue with newer Cups server.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1266303)